# how to calculate an avg recursively for double numbers in array?

Tags: c++

I'm new in C++, and I wrote this code but it doesn't work with double datatype for avg1 function , it backs with nan value. 
but when I change it to int it will work fine and I will get avg for the array.
I tried to divide on 1.0 to cast as a float but without success. 
can someone help with this issue?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double avg1(double arr[] , int _size,int i,double sum)
{
    if (i>=_size)
       return (sum/_size)/1.0;
    sum+=arr[i];
    avg1(arr , _size ,i+1,sum);

}
int main()
{
    double arr[] ={1,2,3,4,5};
    int _size,i=0;
    double sum=0;
    cin >> _size ;
    cout << avg1(arr,_size,i,sum)/1.0 << endl;

}
```

Comment: What do you think `avg1` returns when `i >= _size` is false?

Comment: What warnings does your compiler have for this code?

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions. If you had called another function instead of recursing, what would you expect that function to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're working with recursive functions, you have to remember that you have to return the value of the recursive call. Otherwise, the value is calculated, but you're not making it available to the user. Simply change this line:

```
avg1(arr , _size ,i+1,sum);
```

To this:

```
return avg1(arr , _size ,i+1,sum);
```

Comment: so i have 2 returns
1- return (sum/_size);   >> to return value for  avg1(arr , _size ,i+1,sum) function.
2- return ( avg1(arr , _size ,i+1,sum) >> to return value for double avg1(double arr[] , int _size,int i,double sum) function 
is this correct??

Comment: This is correct. You need one return for the base case of the recursion and another for the actual recursive function calls.